# Why is the output file corrupt / filled with garbage? (Expecting numbers)

Tags: c, io, printf

The following line of code writes unsigned int values into a file but the content of the file is not readable.

```
struct rabin_polynomial
{
    uint64_t start;
    uint16_t length;
    struct rabin_polynomial *next_polynomial;   
};

fprintf(out_file, "%llu,%u",poly->start,poly->length);
```

If I display the out put of the code instead to the command line screen it is readable.

the file "out_file" is not opened in binary mode.

Here part of the content of the output file:

```
 -ÍÍÍÍÍÍp\y";^æó r\ ÍÍÍÍ-       ÍÍÍÍÍÍ
Øâˆ¿»Iðr\ ÍÍÍÍ-      wÍÍÍÍÍÍ7OT-OØÚ‚\ ÍÍÍÍ¤*      L ÍÍÍÍÍÍî›ùçÉç`‚\ ÍÍÍÍð3       ÍÍÍÍÍÍ
Øâˆ¿»I°‚\ ÍÍÍÍðC       ÍÍÍÍÍÍíK¬è‹Ç{ ƒ\ ÍÍÍÍðS      •   ÍÍÍÍÍÍ-Ló3lJ–ÞPƒ\ ÍÍÍÍ…]
```

And here is the expected out put:

```
0,2861 
2861,4096 
6957,3959 
10916,2380 
13296,4096 
17392,4096
```

Comment: Are both numbers unreadable, or only one of them?

Comment: Please include the corresponding file contents / file hex dump as well as the expected values for said output. It might be simplest to throw them to stdout first/as well.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I have posted parts of the outputs

Comment: @pst: I have posted parts of the outputs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're not getting the textual values you expect, it's *possibly* down to the fact that you're using incorrect format specifiers (I'm assuming you've *populated* the variables you're trying to print here, though you may want to confirm this).

`%llu` is explicitly for `unsigned long long int` which is not necessarily the same width as `uint64_t`.

In C99, `inttypes.h` has macros for the format specifiers to be used for the exact-width and -at-least-as-wide-as data types.

For example:

```
uint64_t xyzzy = 42;
printf ("Number is: %" PRIu64 "\n", xyzzy);
```

In this case, `PRIu64` means the `printf` format specifier, unsigned decimal output, for a 64-bit exact width variable. There are a wide variety of others for varying output types, plus equivalents for the `scanf` family as well (starting with `SCN`).

Section `7.8.1 Macros for format specifiers` of C99 lists them in detail.

---

Based on your update where you're not getting incorrect numbers but are rather getting what could only be described as rubbish, I would say your problems lie elsewhere. Even with corrupt pointers or data, I would not expect `fprintf` to generate non-numeric data for numeric format strings. It's certainly *possible* since it's undefined behaviour but very unlikely.

You *could* get that sort of output for strings but that's not the case here.

In other words, I think you have to look elsewhere in your code for (as an example) memory corruption issues.

One thing you could do to test if the problem lies in the line you think it does, is to change it to:

```
printf("DEBUG: %llu,%u\n",poly->start,poly->length);
fprintf(out_file, "%llu,%u",poly->start,poly->length);
```

and see what comes out on the terminal.

Comment: The '%' is not included in the macros from inttypes.h, so it must still be in the format string.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to share your read and write parts of your code for us to help you. But looking at the content written into the out file, it looks like an issue with format specifiers in `fprintf()` and `fscanf()`.

The following program may serve you as a reference.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LEN 6

int main(void)
{
    unsigned long long start[LEN] = {0, 2861, 6957, 10916, 13296, 17392};
    unsigned short int length[LEN] = {2861, 4096, 3959, 2380, 4096, 4096};
    int i;
    unsigned long long s;
    unsigned short int l;
    FILE *out_file, *in_file;

    if ((out_file = fopen("out_file", "w")) == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: unable to open out_file\n");
        return -1;
    }

    for (i=0; i<LEN; i++)
        fprintf(out_file, "%llu,%hu \n",start[i], length[i]);

    fclose(out_file);


    if ((in_file = fopen("out_file", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: unable to open out_file\n");
        return -1;
    }

    for (i=0; i<LEN; i++) {
        fscanf(out_file, "%llu,%hu \n", &s, &l);
        printf("start = %llu - length = %hu \n", s, l);
    }

    fclose(in_file);

    return 0;
}
```

Please note that the `format` (2nd argument) in the `fscanf()` and `fprintf()` must match when `reading` and `writing` the lines respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Please check content of file with hex editor and compare with actual values of poly structure.

You will see what is problem.